# Node.js debugger has a default value of --inspect-brk=PORT without specifying this in the script

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, mocha.js

When I run my mocha tests in debug mode, Node.js debugger has a default value used as the `--inspect-brk=` value.
Without specifying it in the script, my test script looks like that

```
--timeout=15000 --appName=ejbrowser --role=adminUserOne --env=tst --reporter=spec tests/api/ejbrowser/devices/all.spec.js --failureFatal=1
```

But when I run it with debug mode the script that is being executed is:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\repos\yyc-api-ui-automation\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha --inspect-brk=57629 --appName=ejbrowser --role=adminUserOne --env=tst --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --reporter=mochawesome tests/ui/-common/-health-checks-lvl1/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --timeout 0 --ui bdd --reporter "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3\plugins\NodeJS\js\mocha-intellij\lib\mochaIntellijReporter.js"
```

Where does this value `--inspect-brk=57629` come from?

The project that I work on doesn't accept this parameter in commandLineArgs and I had to modify it to accept { partial: true} which is not perfect. So I am trying to understand what is populating this value.

I use IntelliJ idea 2021.3.2 Ultimate.

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "cloudexa-yyc-automation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Java Script | Selenium Functional Automation Tests with Mocha / API Automation Tests with Supertest",
  "author": "Valeriu Jecov",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "index.js",
  "homepage": "",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://jira.esq.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa",
    "email": "valeriu.jecov@cloudexa.com"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://git.esq.com/esq/qa/automation/automation"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test:all": "mocha --timeout 5000 --reporter=mochawesome tests/*/*.js --failureFatal=1",
    "api:all": "mocha --timeout 10000 --reporter=mochawesome tests/api/*.js --failureFatal=1",
    "api:amq": "mocha --timeout=10000 --reporter=spec tests/api/__playgrounds/amqpTest.js --failureFatal=1",
    "api:gorest": "mocha --timeout 5000 --reporter=mochawesome tests/api/__playgrounds/optimized-users-posts.js --failureFatal=1",
    "api:stardust:all": "mocha --timeout=15000 --reporter=spec tests/api/stardust/StardustPOC/all.spec.js --failureFatal=1",
    "api:ejbrowser:devices": "mocha --timeout=15000 --reporter=spec tests/api/ejbrowser/devices/all.spec.js --failureFatal=1",
    "api:checkbrowser:check-files": "mocha --timeout=15000 --reporter=spec tests/api/checkbrowser/check-files/all.spec.js --failureFatal=1",
    "ui:all": "mocha --timeout=30000 --slow=2000 tests/ui/*/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:healthChecks:lvlOne:all": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 tests/ui/-common/-health-checks-lvl1/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:healthChecks:lvlOne:loginLogOut": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 tests/ui/-common/-health-checks-lvl1/logInLogOut.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:healthChecks:lvlOne:switcher": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 tests/ui/-common/-health-checks-lvl1/switcher.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:healthChecks:lvlTwo:ejbrowser_mercy": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 tests/ui/ejbrowser/mercyAndAdele/mercy_all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:healthChecks:lvlTwo:ejbrowser_adele": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 tests/ui/ejbrowser/mercyAndAdele/adele_all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:healthChecks:lvlTwo:ejbrowser": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=ejbrowser tests/ui/ejbrowser/-health-checks/two.spec.js --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:healthChecks:lvlTwo:incidentmanager": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=incidentmanager ./tests/ui/incidentmanager/-health-checks/two.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:healthChecks:lvlTwo:monitoring": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=monitoring tests/ui/monitoring/-health-checks/two.spec.js --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:incidentmanager:crud:incidents": "mocha --timeout=80000 --slow=2000 --appName=incidentmanager ./tests/ui/incidentmanager/create-edit-delete-incident/crud-incident.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:monitoring:all": "mocha --timeout=80000 --slow=2000 --appName=monitoring tests/ui/monitoring/-health-checks/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:dataanalyzer:all": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=dataanalyzer ./tests/ui/dataanalyzer/*/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:dispatcher:all": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=dispatcher ./tests/ui/dispatcher/-health-checks/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:documentation:all": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=documentation ./tests/ui/documentation/-health-checks/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:fieldservice:all": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=fieldservice ./tests/ui/fieldservice/-health-checks/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:obadminclient:all": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=obadminclient ./tests/ui/obadminclient/-health-checks/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:rbac:all": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=rbac ./tests/ui/rbac/*/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:reporter:all": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=reporter ./tests/ui/reporter/-health-checks/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome",
    "ui:workspace:all": "mocha --timeout=60000 --slow=2000 --appName=workspace ./tests/ui/workspace/-health-checks/all.spec.js --browserClient=chrome --failureFatal=1 --reporter=mochawesome"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/node": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.9",
    "@babel/register": "^7.13.8",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "browserstack-local": "^1.4.8",
    "chai": "^4.3.3",
    "command-line-args": "^4.0.6",
    "deferred": "^0.7.11",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "faker": "^5.4.0",
    "fs-extra": "^9.1.0",
    "iedriver": "^3.150.1",
    "jira-client": "^6.21.1",
    "jshint": "^2.12.0",
    "jsonfile": "^6.1.0",
    "mocha": "^9.2.1",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "npm": "^8.5.4",
    "rhea": "^1.0.24",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.1.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3"
  },
  "jshintConfig": {
    "esversion": 6,
    "laxcomma": true,
    "expr": true
  }
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Could you add your package.json scripts section to the question?

Comment: I edited the main question with package,json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what caused it. My temporary directory contains spaces and there's no way to escape spaces when passing it to NODE_OPTIONS unfortunately. So the IDE uses the explicit --inspect switch. As a work around I specified a different TEMP dir in Help > Edit Custom VM Options (Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\tmp) and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

### How to disable the debug mode (node's inspect features)

Remove your debug configurations from intellij using the "-" button. Or just run you application in "run mode", not using the "run debug" mode from the IDE.

[image: run/debug configurations]

### How to choose the debug port number

57629 is just the default port number for debug configured by intellij.

To change it, open intellij and go to Run | Edit Configurations | Add New Configuration | Attach to Node.js/Chrome

Then, change the Port field value.

[Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html)

Comment: Thanks but the question is why do i have --inspect-brk=PORT without even specifying this in the script. Can I get rid of this?

Comment: Try running you application using just the "Run" mode from Idea and not the "Debug" run mode.

Comment: when i use run mode no issues at all, the --inspect-brk option is not there. The problem is  when I want  to use debug mode locally. I don't have any debug configurations set as well. This is why I can't understand where this flag is coming from

Comment: It's the default idea debug configuration. You can customize the port using the process I've described in the answer. Otherwise, if you can always run the application directly from the terminal, writing your customized command script.

Comment: my co-workers run the same project , however they don't see the same behavior so it has to be customized somehow by enabling the flag? They use the same IDE as well.

Comment: I found what caused it, my temporary directory contains spaces, and there's no way to escape spaces when passing it to NODE_OPTIONS unfortunately, so the IDE uses the explicit --inspect switch. as a work around I specified a different TEMP dir in Help > Edit Custom VM Options (Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\tmp) and it solved the issue